# ASP.NET Eager Loading Cycle

Tags: linq, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have a problem with eager loading childrens in EF 4.1 Model-First.

I have 2 entities, Person and Job.
An association OneToMany from Person to Job and an association OneToMany from Job to Person.
(This is just an example)

When I do:

```
dbContext.Person.Include(i => i.Job)
```

I get a Person 'p' entity which has a link with a Job 'j' on the first association, and on the second association 'j' has a link with 'p', and so on..

There I have a 'infinit' cycle.

I want to tell EF for example:

```
dbContext.Person.Include(i => i.Job.NotInclude(j => j.Person))
```

I hope I have explained myself well.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to sort out the associations. OneToMany from Person to Job _and_ OneToMany from Job to Person is contradictory. So is OneToMany from Person to Job _and_ `Person.Include(i => i.Job)`. I think you need many-to-many using a junction table. Or you should bring the example closer to your real model.